Use a table as reference to replace values in a column in another table
Say this query returns the below table:
select * from #test1




equip_id
child_nickname




10
A


20
B


30
C


40
D


50
E


60
F


70
G


80
H


90
I


A0
J







Another query returns this data
select *
from #finaloutput
where EquipId like '%00%'
and ParamName like 'MVE';




Equip
Recipe
ParamName
ParamValue




00
recipe1
MVE
(C)&(D)&J


00
recipe2
MVE
E&G&F



how do i make it return like this instead using the first table as reference ? :



Equip
Recipe
ParamName
ParamValue




00
recipe1
MVE
(30)&(40)&A0


00
recipe2
MVE
50&70&60



DECLARE replace_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT equip_id, child_nickname 
FROM #test

OPEN replace_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM replace_cursor 
INTO @equip_id, @child_nickname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #finaloutput
    SET ParamValue = REPLACE(ParamValue, @equip_id, @child_nickname)
    WHERE ParamValue LIKE '%' + @equip_id + '%'

    FETCH NEXT FROM replace_cursor 
    INTO @equip_id, @child_nickname
END

CLOSE replace_cursor
DEALLOCATE replace_cursor

The above is not converting
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

The version of SSMS you are using isn't relevant, what might be relevant is the version of SQL Server you are using e.g. select @@version

As I am sure you can now see, the issue is with how your data is stored. If you stored it correctly you wouldn't have this issue. So split it into 2 problems, 1) split out the string into codes. Then join the results on your code table.

Thanks for your input. Im using version 19. Do you mean to split out the characters in ParamValue first?

That's what I would do, string split on & , remove the brackets then join on your other table. Hmmm but then you have to know you removed the bracketa to add them back. You can certainly do that without a cursor. All in all a bad design. Are you sure you need multiple values in your results? Why not keep the data normalised once you split it?

Not sure how this supposed to work, you have letter A in your equip_id, so there's a risk it gets overwritten in the cursor depending on how the row order is

Are you open to correcting the design? This should be a tree (looks like an attempt at an abstract syntax tree) Using strings and delimiters in relational-databases is a well known Anti-Pattern

As mentioned, you have the conditions backwards.
Don't use a cursor, it's very inefficient. Instead construct a dynamic SQL statement with a bunch of REPLACE
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql =
  CONCAT('
UPDATE #finaloutput
SET ParamValue = ',
    REPLICATE('REPLACE(', COUNT(*)),
    'ParamValue, ',
    STRING_AGG(
      CONCAT(
        QUOTENAME(t.child_nickname, ''''),
        ', ',
        QUOTENAME(t.equip_id, ''''),
        ')'
      ),
      ', '
    )
  )
FROM #test t;

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

db<>fiddle

Just modify your SQL Server cursor variables with this.

You have to find child_nickname from ParamValue & replace it with equip_id.

But in your cursor you try to find equip_id & replace it with child_nickname which is wrong.
Try this cursor:
DECLARE @equip_id VARCHAR(8), @child_nickname VARCHAR(8);

DECLARE replace_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT equip_id, child_nickname 
FROM #test

OPEN replace_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM replace_cursor 
INTO @equip_id, @child_nickname

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #finaloutput
    SET ParamValue = REPLACE(ParamValue, @child_nickname, @equip_id)
    WHERE ParamValue LIKE '%' + @child_nickname + '%'

    FETCH NEXT FROM replace_cursor 
    INTO @equip_id, @child_nickname
END

CLOSE replace_cursor
DEALLOCATE replace_cursor

You can verify here : https://dbfiddle.uk/HDlHc-Cz

A better solution would be to remove the cursor completely.

Thanks for your feedback, however, tried this but it still doesn't seem to replace the values.

This worked fine for me. https://dbfiddle.uk/cy1g7_EX Note that global cursor is a bad idea, better declare it LOCAL

@SabreenSageer, I try this in my local machine, Maybe you miss something.

@siggemanne, Thanks for your suggestion, I will try it in future for further queries

DATA
CREATE TABLE YourQuery(
   Equip      INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,Recipe     NVARCHAR(80) NOT NULL
  ,ParamName  NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL
  ,ParamValue NVARCHAR(90) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO YourQuery
(Equip,Recipe,ParamName,ParamValue) VALUES
(00,'recipe1','MVE','(C)&(D)&J'),
(00,'recipe2','MVE','E&G&F');

use multiple replace as dictionary to get your desired result
select Equip,Recipe,ParamName,
  REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE
           ([ParamValue],N'A',N'10'),N'B',N'20'),N'C',N'30'),N'D',N'40'),N'E',N'50')
                          ,N'F',N'60'),N'G',N'70'),N'H',N'80'),N'I',N'90'),N'J',N'A0') ParamValue
FROM YourQuery

dbfiddle
